# 'cut' function for date column not labeling actual dates from data

Tags: r, date, datetime, data.table

I'm trying to bin a date column by every 7 days. If the following date does not land within the 7 days of the previous date, I want the bin to start from that new date and check 7 days forward. I'm using the cut function, but I can't seem to get the function to "start over" when it reaches a new date that doesn't fall within the interval. I have an example below:

```
 ex <- structure(list(svcdate_form = structure(c(17700, 17700, 17700, 
17711, 17711, 17711, 17714, 17714, 17714), class = "Date"), map = structure(c(42L, 
42L, 42L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 43L, 43L, 43L), .Label = c("2019-12-05", 
"2018-08-28", "2018-08-13", "2018-06-25", "2018-04-11", "2019-06-03", 
"2019-04-15", "2019-04-22", "2019-04-29", "2019-05-06", "2019-05-13", 
"2019-05-20", "2019-05-27", "2019-11-21", "2019-05-21", "2019-08-21", 
"2019-05-23", "2018-12-03", "2018-11-08", "2018-11-15", "2019-11-11", 
"2019-06-20", "2019-12-23", "2018-08-15", "2018-08-22", "2018-08-29", 
"2018-09-05", "2018-01-12", "2018-04-28", "2019-03-15", "2019-04-04", 
"2019-02-12", "2019-10-14", "2019-12-15", "2019-02-26", "2019-03-05", 
"2018-07-18", "2018-10-03", "2018-01-29", "2018-02-05", "2018-02-12", 
"2018-06-18", "2018-07-02", "2019-01-22", "2018-10-26", "2018-02-28", 
"2018-03-07", "2019-11-18", "2019-12-17", "2019-07-24", "2019-11-14", 
"2018-02-07", "2018-11-05", "2018-02-13", "2018-08-14", "2018-08-21", 
"2018-09-04", "2018-09-11", "2018-09-18", "2018-09-25", "2018-10-02", 
"2018-10-09", "2018-10-16", "2018-10-23", "2018-10-30", "2018-01-03", 
"2019-02-05", "2019-01-18", "2019-04-09", "2019-04-10", "2019-04-17", 
"2019-12-13", "2018-11-27", "2018-12-04", "2018-12-11", "2018-04-01", 
"2018-03-01", "2018-05-14", "2019-01-28", "2019-02-04", "2018-05-15", 
"2018-02-21", "2018-03-14", "2018-03-21", "2018-12-20", "2019-02-14", 
"2018-04-16", "2019-01-08", "2019-02-21", "2019-02-28", "2019-03-07", 
"2019-03-14", "2018-06-12", "2018-06-19", "2018-06-26", "2018-07-03", 
"2018-07-10", "2018-07-17", "2018-07-24", "2018-07-31", "2018-11-20", 
"2019-09-06", "2018-06-13", "2018-07-30", "2019-02-06", "2019-11-13", 
"2018-12-26", "2018-08-06", "2018-07-20", "2018-03-23", "2018-09-26", 
"2019-01-09", "2019-12-30", "2018-08-27", "2019-08-14", "2018-04-17", 
"2019-12-20", "2019-07-16", "2019-12-03", "2018-07-23", "2018-09-19", 
"2018-11-29", "2019-03-18", "2019-05-16", "2019-09-16", "2019-10-24", 
"2018-02-26", "2019-08-23", "2018-03-06", "2019-03-01", "2019-01-07", 
"2019-07-30", "2018-12-14", "2018-01-10", "2018-03-08", "2018-10-10", 
"2019-10-15", "2019-05-29", "2019-12-19", "2019-05-14", "2019-05-28", 
"2018-09-10", "2019-06-17", "2018-11-21", "2018-11-28", "2018-12-05", 
"2019-04-01", "2019-10-23", "2018-11-16", "2019-03-22", "2018-06-27", 
"2018-10-22", "2019-10-11", "2019-09-19", "2018-07-12", "2018-01-15", 
"2019-12-31", "2019-12-02", "2018-10-31", "2019-07-13", "2019-07-20", 
"2019-07-27", "2019-08-03", "2019-08-10", "2019-07-03", "2018-04-26", 
"2018-03-28", "2018-04-04", "2018-04-18", "2018-04-25", "2018-05-02", 
"2019-08-22", "2019-08-29", "2019-09-05", "2019-09-12", "2019-09-26", 
"2019-10-03", "2019-10-10", "2019-10-17", "2019-10-31", "2019-11-07", 
"2019-01-23", "2018-07-25", "2019-01-21", "2019-12-09", "2018-10-20", 
"2018-02-09", "2018-04-24", "2019-11-20", "2019-08-07", "2019-01-02", 
"2019-01-16", "2018-12-12", "2018-12-19", "2019-01-30", "2019-02-13", 
"2019-02-20", "2019-02-27", "2019-03-06", "2019-03-13", "2019-03-20", 
"2019-03-27", "2019-04-03", "2019-04-24", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-08", 
"2019-05-15", "2019-06-27", "2019-03-28", "2019-06-04", "2018-04-10", 
"2019-06-26", "2019-07-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-02-01", "2019-05-03", 
"2019-05-09", "2018-07-06", "2019-06-24", "2019-07-08", "2019-07-15", 
"2019-07-22", "2018-02-23", "2018-11-12", "2018-08-20", "2019-06-13", 
"2018-10-29", "2019-11-04", "2019-03-21", "2018-07-19", "2018-02-19", 
"2019-06-11", "2019-02-19", "2019-07-29", "2018-12-18", "2019-12-10", 
"2019-10-30", "2019-12-01", "2019-04-02", "2019-09-03", "2019-09-10", 
"2019-09-17", "2018-04-20", "2018-10-01", "2018-01-18", "2019-06-06", 
"2019-12-16", "2019-03-29", "2018-03-13", "2019-07-09", "2019-07-23", 
"2019-03-19", "2019-07-05", "2018-05-01", "2018-06-05", "2018-08-23", 
"2019-04-30", "2018-10-19", "2018-05-31", "2018-01-11", "2019-03-25", 
"2018-04-23", "2019-06-28", "2018-03-26", "2019-08-28", "2018-05-08", 
"2019-02-11", "2018-08-24", "2019-06-21", "2018-08-19", "2019-07-26", 
"2018-08-01", "2019-03-12", "2019-08-12", "2018-09-17", "2019-11-25", 
"2019-09-23", "2018-05-05", "2019-08-20", "2018-09-27", "2018-02-16", 
"2019-05-07", "2019-03-11", "2019-06-18", "2019-12-04", "2018-09-12", 
"2018-12-17", "2018-03-15", "2018-02-08", "2019-04-12", "2019-08-05", 
"2018-03-05", "2018-06-15", "2019-11-29", "2018-09-24", "2019-07-17", 
"2019-07-31", "2018-07-09", "2018-11-19", "2018-11-26", "2018-10-24", 
"2019-09-09", "2018-05-30", "2019-03-26", "2018-07-16", "2019-02-18", 
"2019-02-25", "2019-03-04", "2019-05-10", "2019-09-25", "2019-09-24", 
"2019-10-01", "2018-12-28", "2019-09-27", "2018-07-26", "2018-10-15", 
"2018-05-29", "2018-05-04", "2019-09-13", "2019-10-28", "2018-04-30", 
"2019-04-16", "2019-04-23", "2018-02-14", "2018-04-19", "2019-02-08", 
"2018-05-18", "2019-12-24", "2019-01-03", "2018-05-21", "2019-06-10", 
"2018-12-21", "2019-01-04", "2018-02-06", "2019-10-29", "2018-03-27", 
"2018-09-06", "2019-07-12", "2019-10-07", "2019-12-12", "2018-04-03", 
"2018-10-08", "2019-06-25", "2019-07-02", "2019-04-19", "2019-04-26", 
"2019-05-17", "2019-05-24", "2019-05-31", "2018-11-07", "2018-11-14", 
"2018-03-30", "2018-08-09", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-25", "2018-03-02", 
"2018-06-06", "2018-05-07", "2018-02-20", "2018-02-27", "2019-09-04", 
"2018-11-02", "2019-11-28", "2019-01-17", "2019-09-11", "2019-09-18", 
"2019-12-11", "2018-01-13", "2018-01-22", "2019-11-12", "2019-10-08", 
"2018-12-10", "2018-06-11", "2018-08-17", "2018-01-31", "2018-01-19", 
"2019-11-16", "2018-04-02", "2018-04-09", "2018-05-28", "2018-06-04", 
"2018-09-03", "2018-12-24", "2018-12-31", "2019-01-14", "2019-04-08", 
"2018-06-14", "2018-06-21", "2018-06-28", "2018-07-05", "2019-08-30", 
"2019-01-15", "2018-05-09", "2018-09-28", "2018-04-05", "2018-01-26", 
"2018-02-02", "2018-08-10", "2019-08-26", "2018-08-31", "2019-09-30", 
"2019-07-18", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-16", "2018-01-23", "2018-01-30", 
"2018-08-07", "2019-03-02", "2018-01-17", "2018-01-24", "2018-05-16", 
"2018-05-23", "2018-06-20", "2018-07-04", "2018-07-11", "2018-08-08", 
"2018-10-17", "2019-06-19", "2019-07-10", "2018-08-03", "2019-08-06", 
"2018-04-27", "2018-04-06", "2018-12-06", "2019-10-22", "2019-11-05", 
"2019-11-19", "2019-11-26", "2018-05-24", "2019-02-15", "2018-03-20", 
"2019-04-11", "2019-12-06", "2019-07-19", "2019-11-22", "2018-03-19", 
"2019-10-02", "2019-10-09", "2019-12-27", "2019-08-27", "2019-08-02", 
"2019-08-09", "2019-05-22", "2019-06-05", "2019-10-25", "2019-10-16", 
"2019-11-06", "2018-05-22", "2018-01-08", "2019-10-21", "2019-01-29", 
"2019-08-19", "2019-04-05", "2018-06-22", "2018-06-29", "2019-11-27", 
"2018-10-12", "2018-11-25", "2019-12-26", "2018-06-07", "2019-08-15", 
"2018-04-12", "2019-02-01", "2019-08-13", "2018-05-03", "2018-09-13", 
"2018-09-20", "2018-10-04", "2018-10-11", "2018-10-18", "2018-10-25", 
"2019-10-18", "2018-09-07", "2019-11-08", "2018-05-11", "2019-04-18", 
"2019-12-07", "2018-11-13", "2018-09-21", "2019-01-11", "2018-03-29", 
"2019-07-25", "2019-08-01", "2019-08-08", "2019-09-20", "2018-03-12", 
"2019-06-12", "2018-12-27", "2018-07-27", "2019-07-11", "2019-09-01", 
"2019-01-10", "2018-02-15", "2018-12-07", "2018-09-14", "2019-01-31", 
"2018-01-05", "2018-05-10", "2019-02-02", "2018-07-08", "2018-07-15", 
"2018-07-22", "2018-07-29", "2018-08-05", "2018-08-12", "2018-11-01", 
"2018-03-16", "2018-11-30", "2019-11-15", "2018-08-02", "2018-02-22", 
"2019-03-08", "2018-12-13", "2019-06-07", "2019-06-14", "2018-05-17", 
"2018-08-04", "2018-06-08", "2018-08-30", "2018-07-13", "2019-01-24", 
"2019-02-07", "2018-12-25", "2019-01-01", "2018-08-16", "2018-03-22", 
"2018-11-06", "2018-04-13", "2018-05-25", "2018-06-01", "2018-11-22", 
"2019-12-21", "2019-01-25", "2019-10-04", "2019-11-01", "2019-05-30", 
"2019-08-16", "2019-08-25", "2019-12-18", "2018-03-09", "2019-04-25", 
"2019-11-24", "2019-04-28", "2018-05-27", "2019-07-04", "2019-04-06", 
"2019-01-06", "2019-02-22", "2018-10-05", "2019-12-08", "2019-06-22", 
"2019-07-28", "2018-11-09", "2018-11-23", "2019-08-31", "2019-09-07", 
"2019-09-14", "2019-09-21", "2019-05-18", "2019-10-19", "2019-04-14", 
"2018-03-03", "2018-03-10", "2018-03-17", "2018-03-24", "2018-03-31", 
"2018-04-07", "2018-12-01", "2018-12-08", "2019-05-02", "2019-06-23", 
"2018-06-02", "2019-09-02", "2018-08-18", "2018-01-01", "2018-12-15", 
"2018-05-26", "2018-06-09", "2019-10-06", "2019-09-15", "2019-12-14", 
"2018-11-11", "2018-11-18", "2018-12-02", "2018-12-09", "2018-07-01", 
"2019-05-12", "2019-10-12", "2019-10-26", "2019-09-22", "2018-09-01", 
"2019-06-02", "2019-06-01", "2018-01-07", "2018-01-14", "2018-01-21", 
"2018-01-28", "2018-02-04", "2018-02-11", "2018-02-18", "2018-02-25", 
"2018-03-04", "2018-03-11", "2018-03-18", "2018-03-25", "2018-04-08", 
"2018-04-15", "2018-04-22", "2018-04-29", "2018-05-06", "2018-05-13", 
"2018-05-20", "2018-06-03", "2018-06-10", "2018-06-17", "2018-06-24", 
"2018-08-26", "2018-09-02", "2018-09-09", "2018-09-16", "2018-09-23", 
"2018-09-30", "2018-10-07", "2018-10-14", "2018-10-21", "2018-10-28", 
"2019-12-25", "2018-09-15", "2018-02-24", "2018-06-30", "2019-01-20", 
"2018-07-21", "2019-01-27", "2019-10-27", "2018-11-04", "2018-12-16", 
"2018-12-23", "2018-12-30", "2019-01-13", "2019-02-03", "2019-02-10", 
"2019-02-17", "2019-02-24", "2019-03-03", "2019-03-10", "2019-03-17", 
"2019-03-24", "2019-03-31", "2019-04-07", "2019-04-21", "2019-05-05", 
"2019-05-19", "2019-05-26", "2019-06-09", "2019-10-05", "2019-04-27", 
"2019-05-04", "2019-05-11", "2019-05-25", "2019-04-13", "2019-04-20", 
"2018-02-17", "2019-07-14", "2019-01-05", "2019-03-30", "2018-11-24", 
"2019-01-12", "2018-05-19", "2018-06-16", "2018-06-23", "2019-09-08", 
"2018-09-22", "2018-11-10", "2019-11-09", "2018-01-06", "2019-07-06", 
"2018-07-14", "2018-10-27", "2018-11-03", "2018-11-17", "2018-09-08", 
"2019-03-23", "2019-08-11", "2019-07-21", "2019-08-04", "2019-08-18", 
"2019-01-26", "2019-12-29", "2018-02-10", "2018-07-28", "2019-02-23", 
"2019-09-29", "2019-08-24", "2018-02-03", "2019-06-30", "2018-10-13"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

The **svcdate_form** column is what I'm basing this on. The map column is the output I get after using cut. My code is below:

```
setDT(ex)
ex[,map:= cut(svcdate_form, "7 days", include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)]
```

I've messed around with the include.lowest and right arguments, but the second group in map always starts with 2018-06-25. What I wanted was, since 2018-06-29 isn't within 7 days of 2018-06-18, the bin would 'start over' and count 7 days from 2018-06-29 and include 2018-07-02. Therefore, in the end my map column would only have two labels: 2018-06-18 and 2018-06-29, but instead it has 3, and 2018-06-25 isn't even in the data.

Is there anything I'm missing, or maybe I'm approaching this with the wrong function? Thank you in advance for any help or insight you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
ex[, map := cut(svcdate_form, "7 days"), by = .(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(svcdate_form) > 7)))]
#    svcdate_form        map
#          <Date>     <fctr>
# 1:   2018-06-18 2018-06-18
# 2:   2018-06-18 2018-06-18
# 3:   2018-06-18 2018-06-18
# 4:   2018-06-29 2018-06-29
# 5:   2018-06-29 2018-06-29
# 6:   2018-06-29 2018-06-29
# 7:   2018-07-02 2018-06-29
# 8:   2018-07-02 2018-06-29
# 9:   2018-07-02 2018-06-29
```

This presumes that the data is ordered meaningfully. Depending on previous steps in the pipe, you may prefer to `setorder(ex, svcdate_form)` or something similar so that `diff(svcdate_form)` is appropriate.